# Windows-10 dosn't install in disk

Tags: windows-10

I want to install windows-10 in my PC. This image shows my disk partitions.
but windows doesn't install in marked partition. I didn't work with windows. So can anybody help me?
[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I don't think you can install Windows on an extended partition. It needs to be a primary or GPT disk for that. Oh and FAT16 doesn't really work either. Except if you meant 1.0 instead of 10? What actual selection do you get in the Windows setup?

Comment: @Seth is spot on. Installing Windows on a logical/extended partition is not supported. That said, there are hacks that can make it work: http://askubuntu.com/a/366597/446254

Also FAT16 would never work even with Windows 1.0 since it doesn't support 256GB drives, that's just an erroneous partition type flag.

Comment: Windows cannot be installed on FAT16 partitions, Windows 10 should be installed on NTFS partitions only